# Executing multiple Selenium Web driver test cases in parallel on one machine

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am able to execute maximum 5 test cases in parallel on one machine.
How to increase the number of test cases?

Comment: Did you [ask Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Executing+multiple+Selenium+Web+driver+test+cases+in+parallel+on+one+machine&oq=Executing+multiple+Selenium+Web+driver+test+cases+in+parallel+on+one+machine&aqs=chrome..69i57.140j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) before posting here ?

Comment: yes but did not find anything

Answer (score 0):

You'll typically be limited by the power of your computer (number of CPU core and memory speed and amount). This will relate to the number of browsers you open, and therefore the number of test you can run. To run more tests, faster, use a Selenium Grid, such as SauceLabs (which is free for a trial period).

I talk about this is the book I'm working on -- Selenium WebDriver In Practice.

Alex